# How to remove caret-at (^@) from a string with Python?

Tags: python, null

I have csv file where some of the fields have `^@` before the string. This is causing me a headache. How would I write a function for a given `mystring` to remove the `^@` from it? I have tried `mystring.replace('^@','')` but this didn't work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you see `^@`, usually it's actually a null byte (aka Ctrl+@), not the literal sequence of a caret and then an at sign. As such, remove them with `mystring.replace('\x00','')` instead.

Comment: When you see `^(whatever)` its usually an ascii control character. I believe it's a unix standard that python adopted, but don't quote me.